# Sorting data based on the current system date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck on one query ,

where in i have 52 weeks data which i can arrange according to sysdate by getting the week number and comparing with datas week number.
now what i want to do is if the current week number is  10 i want to arrange all the weeks in descending order like depending on the sysdate week number week10,week9,week8.........week11,

with this query

```
select "Weekly","Quarter","SALES","Monthly",week_number from fiscal_calendar
where week_number <= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD-mon-YYYY'),'iw') 
order by  week_number desc;
```

i am able to sort the data till week 1 but i want to continue  the sequence like ending on week 11
so is there something i am doing wrong 
please advice

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! **[Please don’t use signatures in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT "Weekly","Quarter","SALES","Monthly",week_number FROM fiscal_calendar
  WHERE week_number <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'IW')) 
  ORDER BY  week_number desc) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT "Weekly","Quarter","SALES","Monthly",week_number FROM fiscal_calendar
  WHERE week_number > TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'IW'))
  ORDER BY  week_number) t2
```

**Here is simplified [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db2f0/2)**

Comment: Hi Peter iam getting an error command not ended properly i got the idea what to do

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to wrap it up in outer selects, since you can't have more than one `ORDER BY` clause. See updated answer and simplified SQLFiddle example.

Comment: hi the query is working fine the only problem i am facing now is using it in universe its giving this error ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @GauravTilara Try instead of `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD-mon-YYYY'),'iw')` just `TO_CHAR(sysdate,'iw')` or `TO_CHAR(sysdate,'ww')`

Comment: @ peterm thanks its working now can u tell me what was the issue by the articles i went thru i understood that it doesnot consider 'iw' a part of the standard date format so we were trying to capture this with the 'dd-mm-yyyy' format  am i correct

Comment: `IW` is a literal that allows you to get a week number according to ISO standard. There was no need to convert SYSDATE to DATE, since it already returns date. And for a good measure you better cast it to `NUMBER`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case()` (or `decode()`) in the order by clause ...

```
order by case 
           when week_number = to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'WW')) then 1
           when week_number < to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'WW')) then 2
           when week_number > to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'WW')) then 3
         end ASC
         , week_number DESC
```